# Clustering (x,y) coordinates in Matlab with ellipse around different density

Tags: matlab, plot, cluster-analysis

I have some data points saved in CSV file. Odd columns represent X values, and even columns represent Y values. There are about 30 columns and 800 rows. I want to import those data points in Matlab to make a visualization as the image (1st one) attached below. I can go with single color. As the image shows, my points are exactly similar. And I want to have ellipse around the close points and draw at least two ellipse for each set of points, to show different density.

Please help! If my question is not clear, just see the image, I want something like that, but I can use single color. All the points come from a single CSV file.

EDIT: I am using csvread to get points from CSV file. To read column by column I am using the following code. But I think there are more efficient way to do this. As I said, I have 30 columns and about 800 rows.

```
b = csvread ('C:\Users\Riyadh\Desktop\ThumbTouch All\HeatMaps\Tap 3 Rig R.csv', 1, 0, [1 0 870-1 0 ] )
```

The **second image** shows what I have so far.

[image: What I want]

[image: What I have]

Comment: "I am new to Matlab, and I actually have a short time to do it. Please help!" – is a fast way to get your question down-voted and get no help. Doing some research, attempting to solve your own problem, and providing your code with a specific question is how you can get help here. I suggest that you learn about [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and the [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) function in Matlab to start.

Comment: What does your code look like so far? I assume you've found [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) and [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html), at the _very least_...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know what you mean...

Comment: @Notlikethat: Yes. I am using both functions. I will upload an image with what I have now. Let'see if I can edit it.

Comment: @Notlikethat: EDITS are added. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the columns are .... ? I suppose cluster.

```
 M = csvread ('C:\Users\Riyadh\Desktop\ThumbTouch All\HeatMaps\Tap 3 Rig R.csv', 1, 0, [1 0 870-1 0 ] )
 [n m] = size(M);
 C=hsv(m);
 for i=1:2:m,


 idx = find ((M(:,i)>0) & (M(:,i+1)>0));

 % evaluate center
 xc=mean(M(idx,i));
 yc=mean(M(idx,i+1));
 % evaluate standard deviation
 xs=std(M(idx,i));
 ys=std(M(idx,i+1));  
 hold on;
 %draw
 rectangle('Position',[xc-3*xs,yc-3*ys,6*xs,6*ys],'Curvature',[1,1], 'EdgeColor', C(i,:), 'FaceColor', C(i,:));
 rectangle('Position',[xc-2*xs,yc-2*ys,4*xs,4*ys],'Curvature',[1,1], 'EdgeColor', C(i,:)*0.9, 'FaceColor', C(i,:)*0.8);

 %plot points
 plot(M(idx,i), M(idx,i+1),'.', 'Color', C(i,:)*0.7); 
 end
```

the code

1. import the data on M,
2. then it fetches colums 2 x 2 (`x=M(:,i), y=M(:,i+1)`)
3. calculate center and standard deviation,

finally it draws two circle and points for each cluster.

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added some EDITS. Please consider those. And maybe just a little bit explanation of your would will help me greatly.

Comment: By cluster, I meant the set of points that are close together. These sets are randomly located inside the CSV file

Comment: try it, I use this code but I  have NOT got Matlab with me now

Comment: it gives following error: "Error using plot
Color value must be a 3 element numeric vector"

Comment: try again -C(i) -> C(i,:)

Comment: changed  plot(M(:,i), M(:,i+1),'.', 'Color', C(i,:)); .... but you have got a lot of 0,0 points

Comment: This is how it looks now. [image](http://i57.tinypic.com/2uym2ic.jpg). If you want to add more, please do. Otherwise, I am trying to start from here. I appreciate your help. It gave me a head-start.

Comment: True. There are lots of zeros.

Comment: zeros means not valid?

Comment: Ok. Now I am only considering first two columns. There's no zero. [This](http://i62.tinypic.com/qx7uz4.jpg) is what I have now. I want something like [This](http://i59.tinypic.com/2nleeft.jpg)

Comment: It's taking all the points and drawing two circles. [This](http://oi58.tinypic.com/10dfwvl.jpg) is what it's doing. I was looking for something like [this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2nleeft&s=8#.Uu6yST1dWSo). I think we are almost there.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The image obviously is from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EM-Gaussian-data.svg

This page also says that the image was generated with ELKI; so why don't you try using ELKI instead of Matlab?

For this visualization to make sense, you need to be using EM clustering. I'm pretty sure it already exists in Matlab, and it might actually come with a similar visualization, which is known as **contour plot**.

However, your data might be too small.

You have 30 dimensions, for covariance matrixes to be statistically sound, you should have at least 3*d*d = 2700 rows, as a rule of thumb. For *each* cluster, that is. Judging from your plot, you have at least 16clusters, so you should have around 50000 points. Or much fewer dimensions.

Last but not least, I don't know if the contour plot makes any sense beyond 2 dimensions (maybe 3 dimensions if you have a 3D visualization)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I took this photo from somewhere else though. May be the original source is Wiki. I have no idea what ELKI is. I have little familiarity with Matlab, so I thought, I would take that route...